# Superintuitionistic logics which are not hereditary/monotonic: impossible or possible?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, modal-logic, intuitionism

An intuitionistic Kripke model is a triple $\langle W,\leq, \Vdash \rangle$, where $\langle W,\leq \rangle$  is a preordered Kripke frame, and
$\Vdash$ satisfies the following condition of hereditariness (or monotonicity):

if $P$ is a propositional variable, $w\leq u$, and $w\Vdash P$, then 
$u\Vdash P$.

- Are there intermediate logics (excluding classical logic), including intermediate modal logics (i.e intermediate logics which contain modalities) for which there are no Kripke models in the above sense?
- (If so,)  what is the smallest such intermediate logic?
- If there are no such intermediate logics, what is the proof of this claim?

I was thinking particularly of intuitionistic logics to which is adjoined some modality $\bigcirc$ which does not obey hereditariness. I.e, for which we have:

$P$ is a propositional variable, $w\leq u$, $w\Vdash \bigcirc P$ and 
$u\not\Vdash \bigcirc P$.

---

Edit

It has been observed below that classical logic can be given a Kripke model in the above sense. Does this entail that any intermediate logic can be given a Kripke model?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The term "Kripke model" means a certain interpretation of propositional calculus, namely in the Heyting algebra generated as the upper sets of a partial order (or a preorder). Every such interpretation will satisfy monotonicity by design. If you are looking for something that is not a Kripke model, then it's not clear what monotonicity means (ok, as long as it's a sheaf model we'll be able to guess). In other words, it sounds like your question is a terminological question masquerading as a mathematical question.

Comment: I can put it in another way: monotonicity is a property of *semantics* of propositional logic. It therefore makes no sense to ask whether there are logics which violate it. Even classical logic satisfies the monotonicity requirement, trivially so because there aren't any interesting Kripke models of classical logic. (But there *are* Kripke models of classical logic!)

Comment: I am asking whether there are intermediate logic for which there are no standard Kripke models. There are modal logics for which there is no Kripke model.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: But even classical logics have Kripke models (consider the discrete preorder), so what are you asking?

Comment: I thought there were certain modal logics which had no Kripke models.

Comment: Kripke models for modal logics are a different thing, there we also need an auxiliary accessibility relation, not just a preorder (and such models still satisfy monotonicity by design). As I said, you need to make your question clearer.

Comment: Do you have a proof that there are no intermediate logics which do not have a Kripke model in the above defined sense? Are you saying that because even classical logic can be given a Kripke model in that sense, all weaker logics must be have a Kripke model? I don't know why this would be the case.

Comment: It is wrong to call an intuitionistic logic with an additional modality an intermediate logic. Intermediate logics are by definition the ones without any extra modalities. Any reduct of an intuitionistic modal logic obtained by forgetting about all modalities is an intermediate logic. But if you want to retain your modalities then you cannot call it intermediate logic. This is not merely a terminological quirk. It is as wrong as calling the variety of commutative rings a subvariety of the variety of commutative monoids since the multiplicative monoid of a commutative ring is commutative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every propositional logic $L$ weaker than classical logic (i.e., any logic whose provable propositions are a subset of classically provable propositions) has a Kripke model. Just take $W = \{\star\}$, the frame with a single element, and the trivial preorder. The model is equivalent to the boolean algebra $\{\bot, \top\}$, therefore it validates all classically provable propositions and is a model of $L$.

I should also note that monotonicity is a property of Kripke models, not of logics. A Kripke model is just the Heyting algebra of the upper sets of a preorder, by design. Of course the upper sets are upward closed.

You mention modal logics, but for those we need to augment Kripke models with an accessibility relation, and in any case, monotonicity still holds by virtue of what a Kripke model is.

Comment: Thank you. :) But I did not mean to exclude predicate logics. Is this the case also for intermediate predicate logics?

Comment: Everything I said applies to predicate logics as well. In fact, we can generalize to higher-order intuitionistic logic by expanding Kripke models to presheaf toposes on preorders.

Comment: The reason I asked the question was because I found a logic with a modal operator which was not hereditary. It was suggested to me that this showed that we could not define the operator intuitionistically. But is this line of thought therefore mistaken?

Comment: That depends on pesky details.